# How to set a file in a formControl using Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, file

```
<input
  *ngIf="!logoUrl.length"
  type="file"
  accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
  formControlName="logo"
  (change)="onLogoSelect($event)"
/>


  onLogoSelect = (event) => {
    const files = <File[]>event.target.files;
    if (files && files.length) {
      const [file] = files;
      const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      // TODO: Present Loader
      reader.onloadend = (e) => {
        this.restaurantForm.get('logo').setValue(file);
        this.logoUrl = reader.result as string;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

After setting the file in the logo formControl I go the following error:

> ERROR DOMException: "The operation is insecure."

I read several articles, They are using the same flow. like [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-formdata/).

So why I'm facing the error above?

Note: I'm using Firefox

Comment: Just dont use `formControlName="logo"` n your template, which will try to set the value  back in DOM.

Comment: You can also try `emitModelToViewChange: false` when doing `setValue`, I havent tried that myself.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly @sabithpocker